# Draggable drags out contents instead of container

Tags: jquery, html

I have a draggable container that was working with jquery 1.3.2. I recently upgraded to jquery 1.5.1 and ui 1.8.13 from 1.7.1 and now all of a sudden certain draggable containers that used to drag the whole container and contents now only drags whatever is in the container.

**For example**

```
<div class="dragme" drag_action="hex" value="E7E7E7" id="default_color"><input type="text" maxlength="6" size="6" name="colorpick" id="colorpickerField1" value="0969A2" /></div>
```

*This will drag the textbox input out instead of its container and textbox input together*

**I am initiating the drag with this function**

```
 $(".dragme").draggable({

                        scroll: true, 
 scrollSensitivity: 100, 
 scrollSpeed: 100,
 cursorAt: { cursor: 'move', top: 27, left: 27 },
  helper : 'clone',                 // you will drag a copy of the item around
  revert : true,   
  start: function(e,ui){
   $(this).addClass('fade');        // fade out original item while dragging the clone
   ui.helper.find('.caption').text("I'm being dragged!"); // message in clone
  },
  stop: function(e,ui){
   $(this).removeClass('fade');     // remove fade if dragged item is released
  }
 });
```

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here, you can see that the container is also dragged (because of the black border)...I suspect it's just resizing the container differently when it's being dragged. http://jsfiddle.net/Gf9yn/

Comment: I don't see the problem or the difference... Mind setting up a fiddle?

Comment: Well the JSFIDDLE works perfectly but when I duplicate on my own machine does not. I have boiled it down to my libraries. I am including just this along with the code on jsfiddle when testing on my computer.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>

Comment: How do I duplicate the libraries JSFIDDLE is using. I thought all you needed was jquery min and the ui...

Comment: I upgraded to jquery 1.8.9 and now it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to jquery 1.8.9 and now it works.